# How to remove the color picker code from users-edit.php

Tags: wp-admin

I know I am not supposed to alter Wordpress core. But if I want to use the dashboard user profile page at users-edit.php and remove big chunks of the code (like the color picker) how do I do it. From line 259 to 336 - I want to remove all of it.

```
<?php if ( ! ( IS_PROFILE_PAGE && ! $user_can_edit ) ) : ?>
    <tr class="user-rich-editing-wrap">
        <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Visual Editor' ); ?></th>
        <td>
            <label for="rich_editing"><input name="rich_editing" type="checkbox" id="rich_editing" value="false" <?php checked( 'false', $profileuser->rich_editing ); ?> />
                <?php _e( 'Disable the visual editor when writing' ); ?>
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
        $show_syntax_highlighting_preference = (
        // For Custom HTML widget and Additional CSS in Customizer.
        user_can( $profileuser, 'edit_theme_options' )
        ||
        // Edit plugins.
        user_can( $profileuser, 'edit_plugins' )
        ||
        // Edit themes.
        user_can( $profileuser, 'edit_themes' )
        );
        ?>

        <?php if ( $show_syntax_highlighting_preference ) : ?>
    <tr class="user-syntax-highlighting-wrap">
        <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Syntax Highlighting' ); ?></th>
        <td>
            <label for="syntax_highlighting"><input name="syntax_highlighting" type="checkbox" id="syntax_highlighting" value="false" <?php checked( 'false', $profileuser->syntax_highlighting ); ?> />
                <?php _e( 'Disable syntax highlighting when editing code' ); ?>
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( count( $_wp_admin_css_colors ) > 1 && has_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker' ) ) : ?>
    <tr class="user-admin-color-wrap">
        <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Admin Color Scheme' ); ?></th>
        <td>
            <?php
            /**
             * Fires in the 'Admin Color Scheme' section of the user editing screen.
             *
             * The section is only enabled if a callback is hooked to the action,
             * and if there is more than one defined color scheme for the admin.
             *
             * @since 3.0.0
             * @since 3.8.1 Added `$user_id` parameter.
             *
             * @param int $user_id The user ID.
             */
            do_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', $user_id );
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <?php endif; // End if count ( $_wp_admin_css_colors ) > 1 ?>

        <?php if ( ! ( IS_PROFILE_PAGE && ! $user_can_edit ) ) : ?>
    <tr class="user-comment-shortcuts-wrap">
        <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Keyboard Shortcuts' ); ?></th>
        <td>
            <label for="comment_shortcuts">
                <input type="checkbox" name="comment_shortcuts" id="comment_shortcuts" value="true" <?php checked( 'true', $profileuser->comment_shortcuts ); ?> />
                <?php _e( 'Enable keyboard shortcuts for comment moderation.' ); ?>
            </label>
            <?php _e( '<a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/keyboard-shortcuts/" target="_blank">More information</a>' ); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <tr class="show-admin-bar user-admin-bar-front-wrap">
        <th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Toolbar' ); ?></th>
        <td>
            <label for="admin_bar_front">
                <input name="admin_bar_front" type="checkbox" id="admin_bar_front" value="1"<?php checked( _get_admin_bar_pref( 'front', $profileuser->ID ) ); ?> />
                <?php _e( 'Show Toolbar when viewing site' ); ?>
            </label><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - just added this action hook to the function file.

```
remove_action( 'admin_color_scheme_picker', 'admin_color_scheme_picker' );
```

Comment: Yes that's right, but you said, "From line 259 to 336 - I want to remove all of it.", so I thought you wanted to remove all those fields... anyway, glad you figured it out. :-)